# Select records as groups based on sequence and date

Tags: postgresql, subquery, cte, greatest-n-per-group

I have data stored as:

```
CompID  | Seq | Udate     | Utime
--------+-----+-----------+-------
mx433   | 1   | 1/1/2012  | 13:54
mx433   | 1   | 1/2/2012  | 13:43
mx433   | 2   | 1/4/2012  | 14:23
mx433   | 3   | 12/1/2013 | 13:54
```

I want to archive the data based on older than 1 year, however I want to keep the last set of records for every company based on the highest sequence number. I can't come up with a SQL statement to select this in order to move to another table.

Comment: Please always provide your version of Postgres. And we really like to see a table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) and what you have tried, even if it's not working. Attempts often carry a lot of information. And dba.SE is a Q/A site, not a query generator - there's that, too.

Comment: Also important: how many rows and how many rows per `compid`?

Comment: Postgres 9.3.6. 

I apologize for not providing more information initially, I didn't post what I had tried because my sub-queries were returning multiple rows with the same data so I thought my attempt to be useless at this point. 

The data is typically 4-5 records per sequence, each compid could have from 1-100 sequences, the table has several million rows. 

I will test what you have provided. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The query worked @Erwin Brandstetter, I will say it was phenomenally fast. There is the issue however that if the sequence group took place during the 1 year cut off then the group gets broken. (example row 1&2 if 1 year was 1/1/2012, the 1/2/2012 row would not get moved)

I could do a where exists between the table and archive, if it is in the table, move the rest to archive or vica/versa in a second statement. 

select a.CompID, a.Seq from table a
 where exists (select 1 from archive b
                        b.CompID=a.CompID
                        b.Seq=a.Seq)

But that is a second sql.

Comment: Would you rather keep or archive the whole set if its members cross the 1-year boundary? So archive some rows that are younger than a year of keep some rows that are older than a year?

Comment: It could go either way honestly, but for the sake of example keep in table. I have added the max(date) to the sql and I think it is working correctly, however I suspect there might be a more efficient way to do this. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM tbl t
   WHERE  (select max(c.Udate) from table c where c.CompID=t.CompID and c.seq=t.seq) < (now() - interval '1 year')::date
   AND    EXISTS (  -- is not the greatest
      SELECT 1 FROM tbl
      WHERE  CompID = t.CompID
      AND    Seq    > t.Seq
   RETURNING CompID, Seq, Udate, Utime
   )
INSERT INTO archive(CompID, Seq, Udate, Utime)
SELECT * FROM del;

Comment: If you add essential information like Postgres version, cardinalities and the requirement to keep sets together to your *question* (click [edit](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/101459/edit) left under your question), this would actually be a good question worth an upvote.

Comment: [So do your have your answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple approach (can split sets)

Chain `DELETE` and `INSERT` with a [data-modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) for best performance and to be safe:

```
WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM tbl t
   WHERE  udate < (now() - interval '1 year')::date
   AND    EXISTS (  -- is not the greatest
      SELECT 1 FROM tbl
      WHERE  compid = t.compid
      AND    seq    > t.seq
   RETURNING compid, seq, udate, utime
   )
INSERT INTO archive(compid, seq, udate, utime)
SELECT * FROM del;
```

This is assuming all columns to be defined `NOT NULL` (table definition is missing).

Depending on data distribution, there may be faster solutions.

I formulated the predicate `Udate < (now() - interval '1 year')::date` to be [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable). You should have an index on `Udate` (at least).

Ignoring `Utime`. You should replace `date` and `time` with a single [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) column: `udatetime timestamp`. Smaller, more efficient.

#### Avoid splitting sets

To keep rows older than a year if at least 1 row in the same set `(compid, seq)` is still younger than a year:

```
WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM tbl t
   USING (
      SELECT compid, seq
      FROM   tbl d
      GROUP  BY 1,2
      HAVING max(udate) < (now() - interval '1 year')::date
      AND    EXISTS (  -- is not greatest seq
         SELECT 1 FROM tbl
         WHERE  compid = d.compid
         AND    seq    > d.seq
         )
      ) d
   WHERE  t.compid = d.compid
   AND    t.seq    = d.seq
   RETURNING t.compID, t.seq, t.udate, t.utime
   )
INSERT INTO archive(compid, seq, udate, utime)
SELECT * FROM del;
```

This first groups by `compid, seq` and checks if the maximum date in the group is old enough to be moved.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e9acb/1)

Comment: Brilliant. I suspected there was a better way to do things. 

I also apparently need to figure out the 'code' version of comments.

Thanks!